# Javascript, inner classes, and how to access parent scope efficiently

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

In Javascript, I would like to define a class with an inner (or nested) class.  Within the inner class I'd like to be able to get access to the parent instance. How can I do this efficiently?

Some code will show what I mean. Suppose I define a class, MyType1, which exposes several properties and one function, `SayHello`:

```
(function(){
    MyType1 = function(name){
        this.TypeName = "MyType1";
        this.Name = name;
    };

    MyType1.prototype.SayHello = function() {
        say(this.Name + " says hello...");
    };
})();
```

Ok, now, starting from there, I want to add an "inner class" to MyType1, so I add some new code so that it looks like this:

```
(function(){
    MyType1 = function(name){
        this.TypeName = "MyType1";
        this.Name = name;
        var parentName = name;
        this.Child = function(name) {
            this.Description = parentName + "'s child, " + name;
        };

        this.Child.prototype.Introduce = function() {
            say(this.Description + ", greets you...");
        };
    };

    MyType1.prototype.SayHello = function() {
        say(this.Name + " says hello...");
    };
})();
```

Now I can use these classes like this:

```
var x = new MyType1("Victor");
x.SayHello();

var c = new x.Child("Elizabeth");
c.Introduce();
```

---

that all works.  But it defines a new Child function (or *type*, if you like) for every instance of MyType1.  What I'd like to do is get access to the parent class scope, without resorting to that inefficiency.
Something like this:

```
(function(){
    MyType2 = function(name){
        this.TypeName = "MyType2";
        this.Name = name;
        this.Prop1 = 1872;
        var parentName = name;
    };

    MyType2.prototype.SayHello = function() {
        say(this.Name + " says hello...");
    };

    var c1 = function(name) {
        this.Description = parentName + "'s child, " + name;
        //                ^^ no go! ^^
    };

    c1.prototype.Introduce = function() {
        say(this.Description + ", greets you...");
    };

    MyType2.prototype.Child = c1;

})();
```

But, this doesn't work.  The `parentName` var is out of scope, of course.

Is there an efficient way for the Child instance (in the constructor, or in any class function) to gain access to the parent (MyType2) instance?

---

I know that I could define the Child class to be an independent, non-nested class, then in the ctor for that, just pass the Parent instance. But this creates N references to the parent instance, one for every Child instance. That seems like an inefficiency I'd like to avoid.

thanks for any tips.

---

**EDIT** - the reason I want the Child to have access to the parent instance, is that the parent holds an object that is fairly expensive to create - something like a db connection - and I'd like the child to be able to utilize that thing.

Comment: Ugh, yet more abuse of Javascript to bring in "OOP" nonsense. This language does not have classes: if you want them, use something that does!

Comment: You may find this useful: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html It's a set of helper functions (and explanation thereof) that provides a simple, but efficient, means of creating "subclasses" of "classes" created via prototypical inheritance. Looks like you're doing that fairly manually, so it may save you some trouble.

Comment: @Tomalek: You're quite right, of course, JavaScript doesn't have classes. It is object-oriented and it does have inheritance, though.

Comment: I don't see why you would have to pass a reference to the parent instance to the child if you go with your own last idea. You just need to pass the parentName if that's all you are going to use in the child class. That seems to me to be the proper OO way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Cheeso What's the purpose of the anonymous function wrapper?

Comment: Please use the **`var`** keyword to define local variables. If you want to define globals (please don't), define them explicitly as properties of the global scope.

Comment: @Tomalak What language pray tell would you use other than JavaScript for scripting in the browser?

Comment: @KaptajnKold, I think the point was that the same OOP concepts from other languages should not be directly ported to JS.

Comment: @KaptaijnKold: I'd use Javascript. I would not attempt to turn it into some horrible abomination though!

Comment: @Crowder : I'm not doing prototypal inheritance.  It's a nested/inner class. There is no inheritance in this example. @Vidas - the anon fn is just for scoping help in my code module. It adds nothing to the example. @Tomalak - sounds like you have hangups about what I do with *my* code. Hmmm. Ever think about seeing a therapist about that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, There are plenty of horrible abominations being created every day when someone opens gmail, yahoo mail, etc...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit abominations like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably help you out if you do away with notions like "type", "class", etc. when dealing with javascript.  In javascript, there is no differentiation from "type", "class", "function", "instance", or "object" -- it's "object" all the way down.

Since every "type" is an "object" and is mutable, you get nothing of the sort of strong-typed efficiency gains you might get from Java or C++ by reusing a single type definition.  Think of the "new" operator in javascript as something like "clone the definition and call the constructor", after which the definition of the instance could still be changed.

So go with your first, working example: you won't get any gains by doing something different.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up after many hours:

```
var Parent = function() {
  this.name = "Parent";

  this.Child = Child;
  this.Child.prototype.parent = this;
}

var Child = function() {

}

var parent = new Parent();
var child = new parent.Child();

console.log(child.parent.name);
```

This way you can instantiate as many Parents as you want, with their Childs
underneath, and every Child instance will have access to it's parent instance
through the variable **parent**.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to pass in the parent object to the Child constructor:

```
MyType2.Child = function (parent, name) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.name = name;
    this.Description = this.parent.name + "'s child, " + name;
};
```

And instantiate it with:

```
var x = new MyType2("Victor");

var c = new MyType2.Child(x, "Elizabeth");
```

My justification is that it makes more sense that the `Child` constructor is a "static" property of `MyType2`, instead of the instantiated object `x` in your example, since we are talking about **types** here, which are the same across all instances of `MyType2`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use JSON for this:

```
//code here
var number = {
    real : {
        value : 0, //default value
        rational : {
            integer : {
                isNegative : false,
                value : 0 //default value
            }
        }
    },
    imaginary : {
        //code
    }
};

var number2 = Object.create(number.rational.integer.prototype);
```

Now there may be many issues with this, functional or stylistic. But it is an alternative from the other approaches posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. This declares an inner object - which is **kinda** like declaring an inner class and immediately getting an instance of it. A reference to the outer class is simply added as a object attribute in the declaration.

```
// ES6 - example of an inner object.
class DancingFoo {
    constructor(radio) {
        this._radioListener = { 
            outer: this,
            onIsPlaying()      { this.outer._dancing = true; },
            onStoppedPlaying() { this.outer._dancing = false; }
        }
        radio.attachListener(this._radioListener);
    }
}
```

or if you want an inner class you can create instances of later...

```
// ES6 inner class example    
class DancingFoo {
    constructor(radio) {
        let RadioListener = class { 
            constructor(outer) { this.outer = outer; }
            onIsPlaying()      { this.outer._dancing = true; }
            onStoppedPlaying() { this.outer._dancing = false; }
        }
        radio.attachListener(new RadioListener(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Old thread but I found it trying to do a similar thing. Here's my solution, to use a class with constructor. The parent initializes the class and passes itself to the child's constructor which sets a variable back to it's parent.

```
    const myClass = new class {
        #privateVar = "private var";

        myFunc() {
            return "My function";
        }

        private() {
            return this.#privateVar;
        }

        nestedClass = new class {
            #nestedPrivate = "nested private var";
            #parent;

            constructor(myParent) {
                this.#parent = myParent;
            }

            nestFunc() {
                return "My other function";
            }

            nestPrivate() {
                return this.#nestedPrivate;
            }

            nestParentTest() {
                return this.#parent.myFunc();
            }

        }(this)
    }

    console.log(myClass.nestedClass.nestParentTest()); // "My function"
```